# What Visual Studio extension do I need to view real-time changes to my code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am building a project using ASP.NET MVC CORE. I want to be able to run my project and see the impact of my code changes in real time, i.e., I see the changes on the browser as I tweak things in Visual Studio 2022.

What extension do I need for this?

I realise this question has probably been asked before but I haven't been able to find the answer here or through Google.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-aspnet-core. Dont know if there is an extension for it but most people use CI/CD pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this question this morning. I only need to hit F5 in the browser and the code changes will show.